# SOAP XML valid xsi:type

Tags: xml, soap, hpsa

I'm trying to write a SOAP call and the sample request is as follows:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://server.opsware.com" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:attachPolicies soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <self xsi:type="xsd:anyType">?</self>
         <policies xsi:type="ser:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[]"/>
      </ser:attachPolicies>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Any ideas on what `ArrayOf_xsd_anyType` could mean or how I could find valid options for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `ser:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType` refers to a type that you would expect to find defined in the schema for namespace `xmlns:ser="http://server.opsware.com"`.

I don't know where to find that schema; the recipient of this message is expected to know about it. Perhaps this page helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opsware

Comment: Thank you for informing me about the schema now I have a better idea of what I need to look for.

Comment: I found it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify your terminology, what you showed is not a WSDL, but a sample SOAP Request for a SOAP service. The WSDL is an XML document that describes the XML types that are used in the request and response, as well as PortType, Binding and Service information.

As for the `anyType`, this link provides a clear overview of it's usage:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFTDH_8.0.0/com.ibm.wbpm.main.doc/topics/cbo_usinganytype.html

But the TL;DR is this: "anyType allows any DataObject regardless of type. If maxOccurs > 1, then each DataObject in the list can [be] of a different type."

This is contrast to "complexType" which is limited to a single type. For example if you had an array of `complexType` data, then ALL array values must be of the same type ("Customer", "Address", etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your clarification I will update my question.